# AngularFire auth, template not updated when Observable<User> changes

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, angularfire

I am a casual user of Angular so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

I followed [this lesson](https://fireship.io/lessons/angularfire-google-oauth/) from fireship.io to integrate authentication in my angular app using angularfire.

After signing in, the observable AuthService.user$ changes, but the template doesn't update in the UserProfile component.

Using the code snippet below confirms that the data is there.

```
<pre>{{auth.user$ | async | json}}</pre>
```

This seems to have something to do with the observable being updated outside of the ngzone.
I tried to manually detect changes by injecting ChangeDetectorRef in the component and triggering detectChange from a subscribe callback of the AuthService.user$, without success.

I only managed to make it work as expected by changing user-profile.component.ts to the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.css']
})
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  userData?: User;

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {
    this.auth.user$.subscribe(d => this.userData = d)
  }
}
```

And user-profile.component.html to the following:

```
<div *ngIf="userData; then authenticated else guest">
</div>

<ng-template #guest>
  <h3>Hello</h3>
  <p>Login to get started...</p>

  <button (click)="auth.googleLogin()">
    <i class="fa fa-google"></i> Connect Google
  </button>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #authenticated>
  <div *ngIf="userData as user">
    <h3>Hello, {{ user.displayName }}</h3>
    <img [src]="user.photoURL">
    <button (click)="auth.signOut()">Logout</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Here are my dependencies, extracted from package.json.

```
{
  "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/fire": "^5.4.0",
  "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
  "firebase": "^7.8.0",
  "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
  "tslib": "^1.10.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
}
```

Any idea of what I might be missing?

Comment: could you share your code on stackblitz?

Comment: Here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kkengz

Comment: It's not runnable as is though, as you would need to provide a valid firebase configuration in the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, you're changing a little the code of [Jeff Delaney's example](https://fireship.io/lessons/angularfire-google-oauth/).

You are using two `ng-template` and also two `async` subscription on your `AuthService.user$`, (one in the `div` container, and also one in the `ng-template` called `authenticated`. And this is the cause of your issue.

With this code below, it will work smoothly:

```
<div *ngIf="auth.user$ | async as user; else guest">
  <h3>Hello, {{ user.displayName }}</h3>
  <img [src]="user.photoURL">
  <button (click)="auth.signOut()">Logout</button>
</div>

<ng-template #guest>
   ...
</ng-template>
```

If you want to keep your initial code, you can consider adding `shareReplay` operator to your `AuthService.user$` observable. In this case, the last value of `Observable` will always be available to new subscription.

```
this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }
  }),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

Comment: Thank you Thierry Falvo, your response helped! Though maybe I missed something but it seems to me that Jeff Delaney's code is expected to work without the shareReplay operator.

Maybe it got outdated with a recent release of Angular?

Comment: You're right! but you can see in [video](https://youtu.be/qP5zw7fjQgo) at 6:58 that code is not the same than code snippet in his tutorial below the video. One `div` with only one `ng-template` only for login. (without a new `async` nested). In this case, you can avoid using `shareReplay` operator. And yes, your code was working but with dependencies mentioned by Jeff just below the video (healthy dependencies). Maybe a good question to be posted on his tutorial ?